# ComboBox Select Item based on Object

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

so im doing like a little Customer Management programm, just for learning purpose.

I have a class "Customer" which contains: Name, LastName, Age, Gender and some more.
Im Loading my Data from a Json file and im populating an Observable Collection with it.
Now as my Screenshot shows below, i want a combobox which displays the Gender of my Selected Customer and its kinda working. the Problem is that the ComboBox has as many options to chose from as i got Customers in my Observable Collection.
So i want to edit the Gender from my selected Customer with my Combobox, therefore it should only have 2 Options  to chose from: Male, Female.

XAML:

Binding Path Customers is the name of my Observable Collection.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxGender" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Customers}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="Gender"
                          SelectedValuePath="Gender"
                          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=SelectedCustomer.Gender}"
                          Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          Height="20" Width="130" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                </ComboBox>
```

[image]

Thanks for your help!
(sorry for my bad grammar..)

Comment: Have you tried setting the content to static items with `<ComboBoxItem></ComboBoxItem>` instead of getting all the genders from your `Itemsource`?

Comment: Don't bind `ItemsSource` to `Customers`. Using MVVM you can create getter-only property in view model which will just do `Customers.Distinct()` or use predefined `List<string>` with two items: `Male` and `Female`.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Yes, i have tried that, so if i remove my itemssource and add two static items, i cant select any of them and it wont display the selected Customer Gender..

Comment: What type is `Gender`? An enum?

Comment: @SomeBody `Gender` is a string, so for example `Customer.Gender="Male";`

Comment: @Sinatr Can you show me an example of the Code? Im pretty new to programming and i don't know how to write it...

Comment: @SomeBody I modified my Porgramm now, so `Gender` is an enum, does this somehow help me? :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i got it running fine now.
I Changed my Customer Class:

```
int Age {get; set;}
....
public Gender _Gender { get; set; }

public enum Gender
{
   Male, Female
}
```

And i changed my XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxGender"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Genderlist}"
                          DisplayMemberPath="_Gender"
                          SelectedValuePath="_Gender"                       
                          SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedCustomer._Gender}"
                          Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
                          VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                          Height="20" Width="130" Margin="0,0,5,0">
                </ComboBox>
```

My Itemssource is:

```
private ObservableCollection<Customer> _genders = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();

public MainModel()
        {
            _genders.Add(new Customer { _Gender = Customer.Gender.Herr });
            _genders.Add(new Customer { _Gender = Customer.Gender.Frau });
        }
```

Now its working fine, just for someone who has the same problem in the future :)